# Recording Audio with Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus 4 using Command-Line

Tags: command-line, permissions, ubuntu-touch, audio-recording

I'm trying to run record audio on my nexus 4 with Ubuntu 15.04 (OTA-9.1) and it's throwing this error:

[image]

BTW: "Zugriff verweigert" translates to "Access denied"

Any suggestions?

---

Update: with `sudo` it doesn't work either

[image]

Comment: Try with `sudo`?

Comment: No, sudo doesn't solve it (see update).

Comment: BTW, you can create screenshots by pressing volume up and down at the same time.;)

Comment: @eDeviser Thanks, don't have the USB cable with me, though.

Comment: You should probably use `parec` instead, as the phone/tablet runs PulseAudio (you can see in your first screenshot that it is using PulseAudio's ALSA emulation), but that isn't going to work either because the terminal app has no permissions to access audio.

Comment: confirmed, `parec` leads to access denied

Comment: Actually, it seems like it's PulseAudio blocking access.

Comment: the terminal app can access the permissions if you install it outside of the apparmor confinement. 
If you ant you can use my own Open Software Hub to install terminal app without confinement, before it is even released (the OSH):
http://opensoftwarehub.org/download/
You don't have to, you can do all manually but just for convenience I allow early access from ubuntu touch phones, even though Canonical abandoned this platform.

Comment: The trust store system for individual permissions like microphone and camera, is separate from the apparmor confinement. The Terminal app is unconfined and always has been, but does not have any way to enable these extra permissions (and may not help if it did, IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'SnapRecorder' from the Ubuntu Store instead of using the commandline.

Comment: Ok, SnapRecorder works ... but it explicitly asks for permission to allow recording. Maybe arecord needs this, too.

Answer (score 0):

To record from the command line on a phone/tablet running the Ubuntu images, you will have to use the pulseaudio tools, parec or parecord.

For the permissions issue, you will likely have to add the Terminal app, or possibly the parec/parecord tools, manually to the *Trust Store* db for the microphone permission, so that pulseaudio will allow recording. (I'll have to refresh my memory on how to do this exactly, and update later though. Until then, I might suggest to install an app that does audio recording.)

There is no ALSA device available inside Ubuntu, so standard ALSA tools like arecord will not work. The audio hardware is managed by the Android audio subsystem, and pulseaudio connects to this via libhybris (the library to connect to the Android HAL).